# Suport Vector machine (SVM) training using multiple features

Tags: python, r, svm

I am trying to train my svm algorithm with a point dataset extracted from GPS. My data instances (e.g x1, x2, x3,... xn) have a set of attributes (speed, coordinates, etc). I consider the line between two data instances (points) as a segment and I am trying to train my algorithm using more than one features (attributes) and with a moving order. Considering I have my data in a CSV file, what I am trying to do is:

```
1st row: x1(speed, lon, lat), x2(speed,lon, lat), x3(speed,lon, lat)
2nd row:x2, x3, x4
3rd row: x3, x4, x5
```

and so on.

By doing this, I will train my algorithm to learn sequences, which is what I am trying to do.
My question is; How will I train it in the form of sequence? and how this sequence will include more than one features?

I am keen to use either R or Python, though I am more familiar with R. as far as I'm aware of the sklearn library in Python may be useful as well, but I do not understand the form that the training set has to have to train the svm.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: An SVM is a type of classifier - it learns a mapping from a vector of features `x` to a vector of labels `y`. What are the labels that you are trying to predict in this case? What precisely do you mean by *"learn sequences"*?

Comment: Hi ali_m, thank you for your reply. The labels will be actually 1 or 0. What I want to do is study behaviours, with regards to these GPS points. So consider that 1 will be a normal behaviour and 0 an abnormal. But there might be a subsequence that might be abnormal, and  not the whole sequence of events itself. That's why I am trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

after reading reading the description you gave to ali_m , why you choosed SVM? An alternative could be insted of using SVM(supervised learning) , use "anomaly detection"(unsupervised learning) where abnormal in your case would be an anomaly and you could vary the threshold and play with it.

Comment: Hello Luis and thanks for replying. I am not very sure of how to do this with unsupervised learning. This is my first project in ML and anomaly detection and that is the reason I have chosen SVMs (I do not have to develop new features). Though, I have to find a way to model the anomaly in the subsequence I mentioned earlier and that was the only thing came in mind. If you could help with this, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I didnt fully underastand your problem, can you share an example of how your data is organized in your training set and whats the value you are trying to predict on new examples ?

Comment: HI Luis. I want to train my algorithm in a way that it will read segments. I want each learning line to be "continuous". this way, there will be a "sliding window" in the way the algorithm learns the data, and I will be able to extract anomalies in each segment. I am not sure this is clear though.

Comment: I haven't managed to create a training set yet. What I am trying to do is train the algorithm with my variables (speed, coordinates, etc) and use labels such as normal/abnormal. by training the algorithm the way I am thinking of, I will eventually get new labels for each row. or at least, this is what I think.

Comment: Ohh, i think that maybe you are mixing ideas and techniques ,and my comments based on your answers will be:
- You cant train a SVM if you dont have a training set

Comment: Ohh, i think that maybe you are mixing ideas and techniques ,and my comments based on your answers will be:
-You cant train a SVM if you dont have a training set
-In your training set you need examples that your algorithm will use to learn from, but for every example you need a list of features(or variables) and a label(in your case, you say normal or abnormal)
-Once you have trained based on this data, you use your results to predict the label on new examples, every one of this new examples will need to have the same features or variables  as tthe training set.

Comment: Id suggest researching how SVM(and in general supervised learning classification) as it will learn labels,not sequences and determine if it is what you need. And also suggest reading and researching unsupervised learning anomaly detection, and frequent pattern mining algorithms like apriori or eclat, maybe a combination of both unsuperviside learning and pattern mining is what you need(this is just an idea)